# PHPExel -- как это работает?

Tags: php, excel

Вопрос адресован тем, кто имеет опыт работы с **PHPExel**.
При запуске стандартных тестов(входят в комплект библиотеки) вылазит ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /home/www/inc/utils/phpexel/tests/01simple.xlsx.' in /home/www/inc/utils/phpexel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 378

В указанной строке такой код

```
if ($objZip->close() === false) {
 throw new Exception("Could not close zip file $pFilename.");
 }
```

Так как сей объект принадлежит классу ZipArchive, то ищем метод close() в ZipArchive.php

```
/**
     * Close this zip archive
     *
     */
    public function close()
    {
    }
```

**А теперь вопрос: это только у меня вызывает нервный тик?**

**UPDATE 1:** PHPExel версия 1.7.8
**UPDATE 2:** версия 1.7.7 работает нормально.

Comment: а класс ZipArchive случаем не абстрактен?

Comment: Если бы всё так просто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё не так безнадёжно. Проверьте права на запись в папку `/home/www/inc/utils/phpexel/tests/` у вебсервера. Возможно, он просто не может записать туда `*.xlsx` из-за отсутствия необходимых прав.

Теперь насчёт close().

Поскольку файлы формата `OpenXML` являются в своей сути zip архивами, для их записи **библиотека использует класс [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php)** из соответствующего [PHP-расширения](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php). Поэтому, для работы библиотеки это расширение должно быть подключено.

Бывают случаи, когда по тем или иным причинам оно НЕ подключено. Для этих случаев существует класс [PCLZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide), который реализует zip-алгоритм на чистом php. Начиная с какой-то версии библиотеки, этот класс поставляется вместе с ней. А `PHPExcel_Shared_ZipArchive` является обёрткой над PCLZip, необходимой для частичной реализации [интерфейса родного класса ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php). Переключение на эту обёртку производится с помощью функции

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

Почему `close()` они не доделали, я не знаю.

Comment: Плюсую за подробности.  
P.s.  
Права выставлял rw для всех.
Кстати, close() в 1.7.7 выглядит также :)